# Is char a[3]={'H', 'i'} and char a[3]={"H","i",'\0'} are the same in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, character

Are
`char a[3]={'H', 'i'}` and
`char a[3]={"H","i",'\0'}` the same in C++?

Its the same since the compiler didn't give me any error when I try to manipulate the first statement.

Comment: If I wasn't sure, myself, here's how I would solve this Scooby-Doo mystery: Step 1: compile both versions. Step 2: load each version into my debugger. Step 3: use my debugger to inspect each object. Did you try that yourself? What did you see?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Bad advice for when UB can be involved (i assume `"H","i"` is a typo and OP meant `char a[3]={'H', 'i'}` and `char a[3]={'H', 'i', '\0'`}`)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If the last char was uninitialized (which it's not), you could see anything in the debugger, including `\0`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It only gives hint when positive, because of UB, implementation specific stuff...

Comment: Can you give us some hints what you wanted to do with this changes? Why did you change the single quotes to double quotes? Why did you add the `'\0'`? Why did you remove the whitespace after the `,`? The last one does not change anything, but why did you remove it?

Comment: I'm seeing `error: excess elements in char array initializer` because of `char b[3]={"H","i",'\0'};`. Unlike JavaScript, a `"some string"` and `'c'` a character are not interchangeable in C++.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/TPEv7r4hz and https://godbolt.org/z/Ee8c4GbGh

Answer (score 2):

The answer is : yes. assuming your second line has typos with the double quotes.

See [Array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization), the sections on  "Initialization from strings" and "Initialization from brace-enclosed lists". Most notably:

> ```
> int y[5] = {1,2,3}; // y has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
> ```